# "Ya le he pasado a él el documento" o "Ya le he pasado a el él documento"

Tags: acentuación

¿Cuál es la frase correcta?

a) Ya le he pasado a él el documento

b) Ya le he pasado a el él documento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Él** acentuado siempre es un pronombre personal mientras que **el** es un artículo determinado (tiene que acompañar a un sustantivo, **el documento**), por lo tanto la opción correcta sería la a).

Siempre que encuentres **él** con acento será la tercera personal del singular, él/ella.

Además conviene recordar que en la frase **Ya le he pasado a él el documento**, **le** es la forma atóna de tercera persona singular que hace de complemento indirecto, por lo que podríamos decir **Ya le he pasado el documento** y estaríamos sabiendo que él o ella es el destinatario.